# Hiding application resources

Tags: c++, resources, sfml

I'm making a simple game with SFML 1.6 in C++. Of course, I have a lot of picture, level, and data files. Problem is, I don't want these files visible. Right now they're just plain picture files in a `res/` subdirectory, and I want to either conceal them or encrypt them. Is it possible to put the raw data from the files into a resource file or something? Any solution is okay to me, I just don't want the files exposed to the user.

**EDIT**

Cross platform solutions best, but if they don't exist, that's okay, I'm working on windows. But I don't really want to use a library if it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Most environments come with a resource compiler that converts images/icons/etc into string data and includes them in the source.

Another common technique is to copy them into the end of the final .exe as the last part of the build process. Then at run time, open the .exe as a file and read the data from some determined offset, see [Embedding a filesystem in an executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546651/embedding-a-filesystem-in-an-executable)

Comment: I'm using eclipse, are there any tutorials on how to use it as a resource compiler?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411040/how-to-add-an-icon-to-an-application-built-with-eclipse-galileo-c-and-mingw

Comment: Does it work for plain ol' images, data files, and fonts though? Cause it shows the example for icons...

Comment: An icon is just image data, I don't know if you can make winres work with arbitrary files. ps see edit

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way for this is to make your own archive format, which would contain all of your files' data along with some extra info needed to split files distinctly within it.